# Python read and write on same USB port

Tags: pyserial

I am trying to use the Raspberry pi4 as a relay station for my DCC++ railway commands. An Arduino mega 2560 sends a command to DCC controller, say "<1>".  I have read the incoming data on TTYACM0 using Python on RPi4.  What want to do now is to write the same command out on TTYACM1 and wait for the really.
Arduino - command <1> - to RPi4 on TTYACM0 then RPi4 - same command out on TTYACM1 to DCC controller.
Reason, two Arduino's can't talk directly with each other hence RPi4 as a go between.
I have tried many versions of code.  I can easily read incoming data but have found no correct syntax to send it on. Help would be appreciated. Thanks.

```py
import serial
import time

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ser =serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM1',9600,timeout=1)
    ser.reset_input_buffer()

        while True:
            line=ser.readline,decode('utf-8')
            print(line)
            serial.write(line)
            time.sleep(5)
```